# Laravel 4: How to remove `limit 1` restriction from Find() in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to retrieve all the tasks details (task_title etc) belonging to one author_id (author2 in this case).

Tests table

```
author_id  task_id
author2    task_1
author2    task_2
```

Tasks table

```
task_id task_title 
task_1  task_title_1
task_2  task_title_2
```

Author table

```
author_id author_name
author_2  authorTwo
```

Model test.php

```
public function tasks()
{  
return $this->belongsTo('Task','task_id');  
}
```

TestsController.php

```
public function index()  
{  
   $test=Test::find('author2')->tasks()->get();  
   return View::make('tests.index', compact('tests'));  
}
```

and the query SQL:

```
select * from `tests` where `author_id` = 'author2' limit 1
select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`task_id` = 'task1'
```

But actually in tasks table, there are more than one value related to author 2 (in this case task 1 and task2 ) but as the sql only illustrates task1.

How can I remove the limit 1 restriction to retrieve all the tasks belonging to author 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test::where("author_id","=","author2")->get()`

You should not be using `find` for anything that is not a primary key, by the way. This is the aim of find: it fetches one item as it assumes that the key it searches for is primary auto-increment (i.e. unique)

Comment: Thanks! Now I can retrieve all the related task by coding `Test::with('tasks')->where("author_id","=","author2")->get()`

Comment: @JackpotK: Yes; However, you might want to look into relationships. Define yourself an `author()` function with a many-to-one relation.

Comment: alright, can you show me how to define an author() function? Another problem I just found, though the sql changes to `select * from `tests` where `author_id` = 'tester2` `select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`task_id` in ('task1', 'task2')` when I tried to show the task details with $tests->task_id $tests->task_task_title, only the task_id is properly shown but the task_title is empty.

Comment: `public function author() { return $this->belongs_to("AuthorModel","author_id"); }` if it works the same as L3. You'll need an Author model.

Comment: Assumed that I've already passed the $tests value to view, should it be correct that I can have task_title and task_id displayed  with the usage of $tests->task_title, $tests->task_id (which is actually from the tasks table).But it fails to show task_title. task_id is the primary key of tasks_table. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: You should not have been using task_id for the primary key. Should have been id. there are ways to revert: `public $primaryKey = "task_id"` will tell Laravel to use "task_id" as primary key, which should snap all your methods back in place. Read the Eloquent doc, please.

Comment: I've read it before and to be exact,the reverting should be `protected $primaryKey = "task_id`, it has been set in the model file.Thanks anyway

Comment: @JackpotK: Still used to L3's `public static`. Sorry. Point remains - models, relationships, setting proper ids and not using `where` unless a model would be overkill for it.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues with that.  The main ones being:

- You're using the wrong relationship for a many-many, look into `belongsToMany()`
- It looks like you're trying to look up on a composite key which is not supported
- Find is intended to fetch only one record, and does not limit the result set of a relationship.  As shown by your SQL, you're not limiting your tasks by one, you're limiting tests.  Use `get()` in conjunction with `where()` when you need to fetch multiple records.

Here is a link to the documentation to get you started - http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent